# Separation of function

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis

When can a function of 2 variables say $h(x,y)$ can be written as $$\sum_i f_i(x)g_i(y)$$  I want to know what conditions on $h$ would ensure this kind of separation.

Comment: Do you require the sum to have finitely many terms?

Comment: Alex : Not necessarily! Countable sum is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't require the sum to be finite then essentially anything expandable in a two dimensional Fourier Series will satisfy what you want. For example if $f(x,y)$ is defined on the unit square, then

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{m,n\in\mathbb{Z}}a_{m,n}e^{2\pi i m x}e^{2\pi i n y}$$

for appropriate coefficients $a_{m,n}$. For example, if $f(x,y)$ is continuously differentiable, then the series converges uniformly. Otherwise, you have almost sure convergence for any $L^2$ function by Carleson's theorem.